# How to set up a try/catch for an integer entered

Tags: java, char, integer, try-catch

I would like to know how to set up a try/catch on a variable that is a string but has to be checked against an integer like so:

```
public static void isValidAge(String age) {
    int age2 = Integer.parseInt(age);
    try {
        if(age2 <= 0 || age2 >= 150) {
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        if(age2 <= 0) {
            System.err.print("Age can not be 0 or negative.");
        }
        else if (age2 >= 150) {
            System.err.print("Age can not be equal to or more than 150.");
        }
        else if (age.contains("#@$")) {
            System.err.print("You did not enter a valid age.");
        }
    }
}
```

The try/catch must also be able to handle characters and keep the program running still.

Comment: Why throwing an exception, if you are catching it in the same block? You can use simple ifs and not bother with the whole exception deal. Use it on the `Integer.parseInt()` method instead, where it actually does something.

Answer (score 3):

The try-catch should be on the parse attempt itself:

```
 int age2 = -1; //set to an invalid value
 try
 {
    age2 = Integer.parseInt(age);
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
    System.out.println("Error: Could not parse age to number, exiting");
    return; //exit function
 }
```